# Vectorization in Matlab - how to do it

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

Here is my program in Matlab (plot of Fourier series)

```
 clear
 clc
 a0=input('Enter coefficient a0: ');
 an=input('Enter coefficient an: ','s');
 bn=input('Enter coefficientt bn: ','s');
 a=input('Enter lower boundary: ');
 b=input('Enter upper boundary: ');
 k=input('Enter number of terms: ');
 t=linspace(a,b,10000);
 suma=0;
 for n=1:k
 ebn = evalin('caller',bn);
 ean = evalin('caller',an);
 suma = suma + (ean.*cos(2.*n.*pi.*t./(b-a)) + ebn.*sin(2.*n.*pi.*t./(b-a)));
 end
 red=a0+suma;
 plot(t,red)
 grid
```

I read that Matlab code can be significantly improved if we use vectorization instead of loops. Can I do it here?

Comment: It will not help here, due to the time spent on entering coefficients ))

Comment: Can `ebn = evalin('caller',bn);` be replaced by `ebn = bn`? And similarly for `ean`? Those `evalin` might just prove to be the roadblocks to vectorization.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done...

Comment: So could you explain what exactly is `ebn = evalin('caller',bn)` doing at each iteration of the loop? Are `ebn` and `ean`changing after each iteration of the loop?

Comment: they change in every iteration, for n=1 coefficient an (ean) has one value, for n=2 some other...

Comment: Are `an` and `bn` entered as functions of n?

Comment: what type of input are you expecting for `an` and `bn` ? Can you give a typical example.

Comment: both an and bn are functions of n.

Comment: Well I ran this code and `ebn` is same as `bn` for all the iterations in that n-loop and so is for `ean`. But you are saying, they would change. I am not sure what's going on there, as in how `ebn` and `ean` would depend on `n`.

Comment: you can try a0=0, an=0, bn=2*(1-(-1)^n)/(n*pi),a=0,b=0.2,k=10000 and you will get square waveform... for 10k terms you will have to wait some time and if you put k=100k for example it would take forever to complete :) so i try to find way to improve my code

Comment: in my previous example for n=1 bn would have one value, for n=2 it would have another...

Comment: You have `bn=2*(1-(-1)^n)/(n*pi)`. What is this `n`? You have another `n` as the iterator of the loop. Confusing codes really.

Comment: So, when you say "for n = 1 bn would..", how do you input that `n`? I am assuming this is different `n` than the `n` used in the loop - "for n=1:k".

Comment: Well, evalin is used to substitute n (from loop) in an=f(n) and bn=f(n) and calculate 'suma'... Maybe it is easier to start with programming from beginning using some other techniques which would not involve evalin then to modify my code

Comment: Exactly! Avoid that `evalin`! Things would be a lot clear that way.

Comment: This is my first code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979541/fourier-series-plot-in-matlab but it was bad (7656574 times slower than this code involving evalin :) ). Can I find code somewhere? I really don't know other way to programm this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not see a clever way to vectorize your problem, since your integrand is a function of two variables. Of course, you could create matrices of arguments and replace all your loop in a single line, but it is even more slow (at least in my implementation) and much more memory consuming.

However here are 2 ideas how you can improve time-efficiency of your code.

```
%% WAY 1 (original)
a0 = 0;   an = '0';   bn = '2*(1-(-1)^n)/(n*pi)';  a = 0;  b = 0.2;  k = 10000;  t=linspace(a,b,10000);
tic
suma=0;
for n=1:k
    ebn = evalin('caller',bn);
    ean = evalin('caller',an);
    suma = suma + (ean.*cos(2.*n.*pi.*t./(b-a)) + ebn.*sin(2.*n.*pi.*t./(b-a)));
end
red1=a0+suma;
toc

%% WAY 2 (evalin is replaced by anonymous functions)
a0 = 0;   an = '0*n';   bn = '2*(1-(-1).^n)./(n*pi)';  a = 0;  b = 0.2;  k = 10000;  t=linspace(a,b,10000);
tic
fan = str2func(['@(n) ' an]);
fbn = str2func(['@(n) ' bn]);
van = fan(1:k);
vbn = fbn(1:k);
suma=0;
for n=1:k
    suma = suma + (van(n).*cos(2.*n.*pi.*t./(b-a)) + vbn(n).*sin(2.*n.*pi.*t./(b-a)));
end
red2=a0+suma;
toc

%% WAY 3 (using parallel computing toolbox on a multi-core computer)
a0 = 0;   an = '0*n';   bn = '2*(1-(-1).^n)./(n*pi)';  a = 0;  b = 0.2;  k = 10000;  t=linspace(a,b,10000);
if matlabpool('size')==0, matlabpool open; end
tic
fan = str2func(['@(n) ' an]);
fbn = str2func(['@(n) ' bn]);
van = fan(1:k);
vbn = fbn(1:k);
suma=0;
parfor n=1:k
    suma = suma + (van(n).*cos(2.*n.*pi.*t./(b-a)) + vbn(n).*sin(2.*n.*pi.*t./(b-a)));
end
red3=a0+suma;
toc
```

The results are below:

```
Elapsed time is 3.768538 seconds. (original code)
Elapsed time is 2.026532 seconds. (with anonymous functions)
Elapsed time is 2.517645 seconds. (parallel computing with 4 workers)
Elapsed time is 1.105956 seconds. (parallel computing with 12 workers)
```

It is not a huge improvement, but still... Maybe somebody can suggest more efficient ways.